# Set position of Image programatically in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am developing a Windows Store application with C# and XAML in which I have an image being displayed on user screen. On certain event I want to change its position on screen to the coordinates of my choice.

I have tried

```
            Canvas.SetLeft(selectedImage, screenCoords.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(selectedImage, screenCoords.Y);
```

and

```
selectedImage.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, screenCoords.X);
selectedImage.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, screenCoords.Y);
```

But they are not working. I have also tried updating the layout after this. can anyone tell me what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Here is the XAML code:

```
<FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="cv">
                        <Image x:Name="img1" Source = "{Binding ModelImage}" Stretch="Fill" Tag="{Binding ModelTag}" Tapped="ModelTapped"/>

                        <Image x:Name="hat" Source = "{Binding HatImage}" Width="{Binding HatWidth, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="{Binding HatHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" Stretch="Fill" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationDelta="ResourceImage_ManipulationDelta" Tapped="imageTapped" Tag="{Binding hatTag}" Canvas.ZIndex="3">
                            <Image.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform />
                            </Image.RenderTransform>
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
```

I have several images in the grid named 'cv', just removed them for simplicity. selectedImage in above C# code is one of the images in the grid 'cv'.

Comment: I assume you mean a *modern UI* application, since Microsoft has abandoned the metro name due to international trademarks...

Comment: Silliness to me, but Microsoft wants it called either Windows 8 UI, or Modern. One article, although there are easily hundreds. http://www.theverge.com/2012/8/10/3232921/microsoft-modern-ui-style-metro-style-replacement

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out :) Can you solve my issue?

Comment: Can you post `XAML` code?

Comment: @RohitVats Updated question with XAML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by translating my image to the desired points using RenderTransform property.